# What does a plus sign below a note mean?

Tags: guitar, sheet-music

See an example below:

[image]

What do these plus signs mean?

Comment: Possibly [related question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/78244/2600), if the piece dates from baroque era - details are missing in the question.

Comment: No, it's a traditional russian song from a later period.

Comment: It *can* mean pizzicato playing, but isn't that the case all the time on guitar? A lot, but not all could be open strings.

Comment: Is this left-hand pizzicato?  I don't know if guitar does this, but can't see why not.  Could also be left-hand-percussive (ie tap rather than pluck)

Comment: Exactly what is the piece?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notes marked with + should be plucked with the thumb. I believe it's known as German finger notation (so Spanish `p` notation corresponds to  `+`, `i` is `.`, `m` is `..`, `a` is `...` or `∴`).

In the piece the bass voice (all the notes with stems downwards) are supposed to be plucked with thumb. It is marked explicitly with the + marks in the sections where it might be less obvious, e.g. where the bass goes above other voices.

Comment: So what do the other numbers, some of which are on notes that also have a +, mean?

Comment: @LaurencePayne The numbers would usually be a hint for the finger to use on the fretting hand. Although I don't have a clue about the circled one

Comment: @DavidW yes, arabic numbers indicate fretting hand fingers. Circled arabic number indicates the string number. For completeness, roman numbers (not present in this score) indicate the fretting hand position (i.e. fret on which the first finger is), or sometimes harmonics fret. I wonder if we a guitar notation wiki?

Comment: I'd have thought stems down would indicate thumb, since all that is a 'bass line'. Seem to remember many decades ago, in piano music, + meant play with thumb, but that was piano!

Comment: @Tim yes, this notation is sometimes used in guitar scores.

Comment: Seems like I need to do more score reading! But as I say, stems down is fairly apparent. I don't think I'd play any of the stem-down notes with anything *but* thumb.

Answer (score 4):

The question here appears to be about a guitar part.  For completeness, here's the full set of possibilities as collected by [Dolmetsch](https://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm)

> in string parts: written in combination with pizz. over or under the
> note-head, meaning: play a left hand pizzicato

> applied to chord
> names or numbers: A, Aug. or +: an augmented interval

> in
> percussion parts: a dead stroke, achieved by holding the mallet on the
> instrument after the attack to dampen the vibration. Dead strokes are
> commonly notated with a plus sign (+) over the note. Ringing notes in
> a passage with dead strokes can be indicated with a circle (o) over
> them; this is not necessary but can help to clarify. D.S. or
> staccato dots are other common indications for dead stroke. These
> notations are not standard and should be explained at the top of the
> score and part

> in early music, particularly that for
> wind-instruments: the 'plus' sign indicates a musical ornament,
> usually a trill
>
> in French horn parts: a '+' above notes to be stopped, followed by a
> 'o' above notes that are open for longer stopped passages the word is
> just written out:     English stopped open     German gestopft    offen
> Italian   chiuso  aperto      French  bouché  ouvert

Comment: Since the first choice seems to require a coexisting *pizz* to trigger: nothing seems to match?

Comment: From your favourite! I considered l.h.pizz., but some of those notes are fretted, which doesn't make a lot of sense then. Nothing else makes sense either.